# How do I share enums throughout multiple classes?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, enums

Say I have a class A with a reference to another class (class B) as a delegate. That delegate class has defined a bunch of enumerated values to identity states.

In class A, how would I set the delegate (class B) to an enum representing one of the states? Class A would not be aware of any of these states, right?

Comment: You could just define the enum in the delegate class' header, better yet make a separate delegate protocol with the needed enums. Any class needing to either be the delegate (or have a delegate of the same type) would then have access to the enums...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Class `A` would not be aware of any of these states, right?

Absolutely. In order to make your class `A` aware of the `enum`, put its definition in `B`'s header. Optionally, you may `typedef` your `enum` so that you wouldn't have to type `enum` with the tag:

```
typedef enum {
    kClassBState1
,   kClassBState2
,   kClassBState3
} ClassBState;
```

Class `B` can define methods that take `ClassBStates` like this:

```
-(void)switchToState:(ClassBState)newState;
```

Class `A` can call this method like this:

```
ClassB *instB = [[ClassB alloc] init];
[instB switchToState:kClassBState3];
```

Comment: And remember that Apple provides the `NS_ENUM` and `NS_OPTIONS` macros that will allow Xcode to do code completion and improved type checking: http://nshipster.com/ns_enum-ns_options/

Answer (score 2):

You can define the enum in another .h file and then #import that file in both classes (*.h) file. That would be enough.

Then you need just to refer the enum type.